# Getting the form fields without jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example:

```
<form id ="f1">
    <input type="text" id="quantity" />
</form>
```

There is obviously some overhead associated with jquery selectors. So, once I got the form using a selector, I don't want to use another selector to get its field as it is coded below:

```
var $form = $('#f1');
var $field = $('#f1 #quantity');
```

Is there an alternative to get field-quantity without using selectors? Is there something like:

`var $qty = $form.quantity;`

Comment: You want get all form field value?

Comment: You'll probably find, if you try `console.log(quantity)`, that the browser has already initialised a global variable referencing that element...

Comment: @Harutyun: At different pages, I have different needs. In some cases, I need to access and process all the fields and in others, just a couple of fields.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I don't understand. After which one of my statements (in the example above) do you say the global variable will be initialized?

Comment: As soon as the DOM is constructed, on DOMReady/DOMContentLoaded. It has nothing to do with your code, this is the browser's automagic behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (Also here is a fiddle to test on: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvv1xwq/3/):

Example HTML:

```
<form id="test-form">
    <input name="test1" value="1" />
    <input name="test2" value="2" />
    <textarea name="test3">3</textarea>
    <select name="test4">
        <option value=""></option>        
        <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>        
    </select>    
    <input name="test5" type="checkbox" value="5" checked="checked" /> Checkbox 5    
</form>
```

Example with jQuery (Basically the same as the javascript version):

```
// Get the form element by its ID using jQuery selector.
form = $('#test-form')[0];

// Now we can access the inputs of the form by the `name` HTML attribute.
// For example the first input is named `test1`. Then we can access its value using the `value` attribute
console.log(form.test1.value);

// We can do the same for the second input
console.log(form.test2.value);

// Here is an example using a Textarea.
console.log(form.test3.value);

// Example with select
console.log(form.test4.value);

// Example with checkbox
if (form.test5.checked) {
    console.log(form.test5.value);
}

// Example of looping through elements in form
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; ++i) {
    console.log(form[i]);
}
```

Example javascript:

```
// Get the form element by its ID
form = document.getElementById('test-form');

// Now we can access the inputs of the form by the `name` HTML attribute.
// For example the first input is named `test1`. Then we can access its value using the `value` attribute
console.log(form.test1.value);

// We can do the same for the second input
console.log(form.test2.value);

// Here is an example using a Textarea.
console.log(form.test3.value);

// Example with select
console.log(form.test4.value);

// Example with checkbox
if (form.test5.checked) {
    console.log(form.test5.value);
}

// Example of looping through elements in form
for (var i = 0; i < form.length; ++i) {
    console.log(form[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, the plain javascript and DOM work better in this case than using jquery selectors. I was checking if there is alternate to jquery-selector once the form is obtained using a selector already.

Comment: You can still access the DOM elements if you use the jQuery selector. Slightly different syntax Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zcvv1xwq/2/

Comment: That does it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()`:

```
var $field = $form.find('input ')
```

However, since your input has an ID (and we all know IDs must be unique) you can select the input via simply:

```
var $field = $('#quantity');
```

Comment: I would assume find() involves as much overhead as the jquery selectors. And I won't be able to $('#quantity') since there are more than one forms with same set of fields.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique, so if that's the case you have bigger issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "find()" to select the element you want inside the form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="quantity">
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var $f = $("form");
   var $inp = $f.find("#quantity").val("hi");
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcpfygpt/2/

The form is selected and cached in the variable $f. The method 'find()' is used to find the input element with the #quantity id and we use the val() method set a value to the input.